# Multitable constraints for a column value in sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I have a three tables, a project table, there may be many projects, a subjects table, where each project will have many subjects and a condition table where each subject will have a condition and a project may have many conditions.

How to restrict the condition that the subjects can have based on the conditions that the project is linked to given that the subject must be in one of the projects.

Hope that makes sense. Also, I am thinking of using sqlite but if it is not possible to do something like this with the database system does there exist one that can? Preferebly free and sql based ie mysql or postgresql.

Thanks.

edit: some examples;

project A has conditions 1, 2 and 3. All are drawn from the condition table which has conditions 1,2,3,4,5. Now subject X is part of project A so should only be allowed to assume conditions 1,2,3 NOT 4 or 5.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you give a couple examples? I'm not sure exactly what you mean

Comment: mysql doesn't support `CHECK` constraints. The syntax is supported, but the directives are ignored. You could use triggers to simulate them, or do the constraint logic in your client app anywhere you're doing an update/delete/insert

Comment: I added some examples.

Comment: This is a simple JOIN.

Comment: How do I constrain the input value though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

[image]

The key aspect of this design the the usage of *identifying relationships* and the resulting composite keys. This allows us to migrate PROJECT.PROJECT_ID:

- not just directly to SUBJECT
- but also through CONDITION and then to SUBJECT.

Both of these "paths" of migration eventually get merged into the same field (note `FK1,FK2` in front of SUBJECT.PROJECT_ID), which ensures that when a subject is connected to a condition, they both must be connected to the *same* project.

Comment: I think that this makes sense ... As condition is a many to many relationship is it okay to say that this is the intermediary table in that relationship so that the condition table will have another link to a table that stores the actual names of the conditions?

Comment: @user1170304 No, CONDITION is not a link (aka. junction) table. Any additional attributes that describe a condition (such as name) are stored in it directly. There is a 1:N relationship between PROJECT and CONDITION, which is what you specified in your question (_"project may have many conditions"_). If that specification is incorrect, then obviously this model would need to change too.

Comment: Okay, yes, I have made the problem ill defined in that there will be  a many to many relationship between project and conditions. is there any way to alter this solution to still arrive at the correct answer?

Comment: @user1170304 Well, then what you proposed can be done - CONDITION will act as a junction table and CONDITION_NO (or better: "..._ID") will reference another table.

Comment: I just finished checking it and it works! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Condition(
    Id int not null, --PK
    Description varchar(50)
)

create table ProjectCondition(
    Id int not null, --PK
    ProjectId int not null, -- FK to Project PK#
    ConditionId int not null -- FK to Condition PK
)

create table ProjectSubject(
    Id int not null, --PK
    ProjectId int not null, -- FK to Project PK
    SubjectId int not null -- FK to Subject PK
)

create table ProjectSubjectCondition(
    Id int not null, -- PK
    ProjectConditionId int not null -- FK to ProjectContion PK
)
```

Assumptions:

- Subject has an existence separate from Project (i.e. there is a
  Subject table somewhere)
- Condition is the same

(Doesn't make much difference if they're wrong.)

By linking the ProjectSubjectCondition to the ProjectConditions the condition of a subject for a project must be a condition of the project.

Cheers -